# Using Javascript aggregation in druid queries

Tags: javascript, druid

I am trying to write javascript aggregator for my druid queries. i need to to calculate average of a metric "Base_SalesRank".
So far i have been able to this by writing:

```
 {
   "queryType": "groupBy",
   "dataSource": "marketdata",
   "granularity": "all",

   "dimensions" : ["Item"],
   "filter": { "type": "and", "fields" : [{"type": "selector", "dimension": "Item", "value": "MN10CESWW"}]},
   "intervals": ["2018-06-28T00:00Z/2018-07-04T00:00Z"],
  "aggregations" : [
    { "type" : "count", "name" : "rows" },
    { "type" : "doubleSum", "name" : "Base_SalesRank", "fieldName" : "Base_SalesRank" }
  ],
  "postAggregations" : [{
   "type": "javascript",
  "name": "Target DOS Average",
  "fieldNames": ["Base_SalesRank", "rows"],
    "function": "function(Base_SalesRank, rows) {return Base_SalesRank/ rows;}" 
  }]
}
```

But I noticed that many values in Base_SalesRank is 0.

```
[ { 
  "timestamp" : "2018-06-28T05:06:03.000Z",
  "result" : {
    "pagingIdentifiers" : {
      "marketdata_2018-06-28T00:00:00.000Z_2018-06-29T00:00:00.000Z_2018-07-06T08:11:02.499Z" : 3
    },
    "dimensions" : [ "Item" ],
    "metrics" : [ "Base_SalesRank" ],
    "events" : [ {
      "segmentId" : "marketdata_2018-06-28T00:00:00.000Z_2018-06-29T00:00:00.000Z_2018-07-06T08:11:02.499Z",
      "offset" : 0,
      "event" : {
        "timestamp" : "2018-06-28T07:10:02.000Z",
        "Item" : "MN10CESWW",
        "Base_SalesRank" : 0
      }
    },
 {
      "segmentId" : "marketdata_2018-06-28T00:00:00.000Z_2018-06-29T00:00:00.000Z_2018-07-06T08:11:02.499Z",
      "offset" : 3,
      "event" : {
        "timestamp" : "2018-06-28T07:20:21.000Z",
        "Item" : "MN10CESWW",
        "Base_SalesRank" : 5558
      }
    } ]
  }
} ]
```

So i am not getting true average. Now i need to weed out these 0 values and then calucate average. We can do this by using filters

```
{"type": "not", "field": {"type": "selector", "dimension": "Base_SalesRank", "value": "0"}}
```

But I have constraint that I have to perform this filter operation inside the javascript function only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same with just adding a having query -

```
"having": {
    "type": "greaterThan",
    "aggregation": "Base_SalesRank",
    "value": 0
  }
```

If you want to do the same in javascript function than it can be done as below -

1. You should add a dimension (key/value) say "isValid" as "0" or "1" during pre-ingestion json data based on if Base_SalesRank is 0 than "isValid" will be 0 else 1.
2. Apply filter on this field in your query.
3. Use the rows in your post Aggregration.